# Migration from File Manager to Assets

Tags: assets, file-manager, files, migration

I am working on a fully-developed site that is currently live, with hundreds, perhaps thousands of images and files in preset folders using File Manager in EE.

As a pre-purchase question, I guess... I would like to migrate the files & images to Assets, and was wondering if it was as easy as changing the channel fields from a File field to an Asset field?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing just this last week on a few thousand entries. Assets works really well at converting.

First make sure Assets is synchronised with your upload paths. Assets creates a reference to all the files in `exp_assets_files`.

EE File fieldtype stores it's data in the format `{filedir_x}your-file.ext`, where x is the reference to upload paths config.

When changing an existing fieldtype from File to Assets, Assets matches the file name against it's stored reference in `exp_assets_files` and create the appropriate rows in `exp_assets_selections`.

I did have some issues with files starting with underscore. I've yet to work out if this is a real issue or specific to my install.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for a assets fieldtype that's within a Grid fieldtype

Comment: @Bransin This article is a couple of years old, I'm not sure if assets supported grid then and doesn't now or never did. Maybe it's something P&T can answer?

Comment: Thanks for the response Elliot. After much digging, I'm finding there is conflict between Grid and P&T fieldtypes. P&T writes their stuff to support Matrix, but not Grid. Had to roll my own module to populate the exp_assets_selections by going through each Grid column. Gah!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is that easy, I've done this many times. In some earlier versions of Assets I had some issues doing this on a couple of sites, but later versions smoothed out the bumps.

As always, do this on a dev copy of the site first - or at the veery least, take a full DB backup first.